# How can I return an object with converted type from a new operator+ (Template class)

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote a template class for spheres. It saves their central point and their radius. Now I'm trying to write an `operator+` that adds a value to the every value of the central point. The call from my main function looks like this:

```
Sphere<int, double> s1(1,1,1,2.5); // (x,y,z,radius)
auto s2 = s1 + 1.5;
```

While my `operator+` looks like this:

```
template <typename T, typename S> class Sphere { 

...

    template <typename U>
    friend Sphere operator+(const Sphere<T, S> s, U add){ // Sphere<int, double>
        decltype(s.m_x + add) x,y,z;
        x = s.m_x + add;
        y = s.m_y + add;
        z = s.m_z + add;
        Sphere<decltype(x), S> n(x,y,z,s.rad); // now Sphere<double, double>
        return n; //error occurs here
    }
};
```

The error message i get is:

```
could not convert 'n' from 'Sphere<double, double>' to 'Sphere<int, double>'
```

What do I have to change that it works and why is my way wrong?

Comment: `new` is an operator

Comment: was just a little mistake when i created the example code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Sphere` in your `friend` function's return type refers to the type of the enclosing class, so it's `Sphere<int, double>`. Use a trailing return type to specify the correct type

```
template <typename U>
friend auto operator+(Sphere<T, S> const& s, U add)
    -> Sphere<decltype(s.m_x + add), S>
{ ... }
```

Or if you have a C++14 compiler that supports deduced return types for functions, then just drop the trailing return type.

```
template <typename U>
friend auto operator+(Sphere<T, S> const& s, U add)
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

So in your example you have `return n` and n is made of `Sphere<int, double>` and `Sphere<double, double>`.
It gives you the error because you have the value of type `int` and `double` iss the type that the compiler expects in the other `Sphere` function.

Examples:

```
int number;
double(number);
```

or

```
static_cast<double>(number);
```

Comment: But i want that s2 gets the type Sphere<double, double>. n is already from type Sphere<double, double> and now i tried to return n so it would be like: Sphere<double, double> s2 = n;

Comment: Well one way is to just change it to "double" in both or I as I said, to convert the integer value to double (the same type).

Comment: if i understand you correct, you say one solution would be to switch Sphere<int, double> s1(1,1,1,2.5); to Sphere<double, double> s1(1,1,1,2.5); ? That wouldnt be a viable solution since i can't change my main function. I don't really understand what you mean with "'double' in both".